# iOS: How can I view more Unicode?

Tags: ios, internationalization, unicode

I would like to be able to view more Unicode characters on my iPhone—specifically, more [mathematical operators and symbols](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode). Most of these are not visible on iOS and either appear blank or as a question mark inside a box despite being directly accessible through the character viewer on a Mac.

How can I view these characters on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to add fonts to your iOS device which contain the characters which are missing.  This can be done with various apps from the app store, like [Anyfont](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/anyfont/id821560738?mt=8).

You might try the font [Symbola](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/).

Comment: Is there no way to do this for free?  I am definitely **not** a savvy computer user, but could I somehow “load” the fonts from Mac to iPhone?

Comment: Sorry, it's not a simple process, that's why there are paid apps for it, I recommend you spring for the $1.99

Comment: Wonderful!  That's the perfect explanation!